# Can´t delete singular faces that are connected to others

Tags: modeling, rendering, faces

I constructed a big plane via Polyrebuild tool that consists of various planes that are connected to one another.

Now I want to delete single faces in that constructions to have holes in my modeled plane but if I delete one face Blender is always deleting all the faces around the selected face as well.

It happens in other situations too, so it shouldn't be about the plane I created.
Does anyone have a solution for that?

Comment: X -> only faces should remove the face leaving everything else, you might have to clean up some loose verts and edges

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I figured it out thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

It's important to know how selection (and deletion) behaves based on your selection mode

(this thing :
[image: Selection mode] )

When choosing delete from the context menu (<kbd>Right Click</kbd> or <kbd>W</kbd> depending on your settings) the only offered deletion mode is the one corresponding to your selection mode, but pressing <kbd>X</kbd> opens up the complete menu.

Let's take this example:

[image: Different results for deletion]

With only one face selected (fig1), deletion will basically only depend on 3 modes, giving the results you can see above :

[image]

Delete Vertices (fig2), Delete Edges (fig3), and Delete Faces (fig4)